# Growing smaller plants between larger ones

Tags: companion-planting

Some plants, such as cauliflower and pumpkin, grow large and thus we plant them far apart. Is it a good idea to grow other, smaller plants between them though? An obvious example are most herbs, but perhaps there are other ideas?

Comment: You're talking about companion planting. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Pumpkin and watermelons do well planted with sweet corn. Sweetcorn is harvested about the time the pumpkins vines are getting very large. Probably any winter squash will work. Peas and spinach work well with potatoes ; the peas and spinach are gone before potatoes need room. Also flowers like marigolds will share space. For perennials , I planted asparagus with rhubarb . Both like moist conditions and the asparagus makes very little shade , plus slowing the rhubarb seems a good idea for me ( how many pies can you make ?).

Comment: I've heard of the pumpkin, sweetcorn, runner bean trio which I plan on trying out. I like the asparagas rhubarb idea. İ plan on making jam from the rhubarb too; I've had some very tasty rhubarb+ginger jam.

Comment: An acquaintance of mine had a small rhubarb farm , so I ended up with 4 plants - about 4 times more than a normal person can use , even if you only harvest once.